# Graphical problem with desktop cube, Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: graphics, cube

I'm new to Linux and need some help!

I have problem with desktop cube,  Ubuntu 14.04.4. Can't describe it, so here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I enabled all this,
    Composite, 
    OpenGL, 
    Desktop Cube, 
    Rotate Cube, 
    Animations, 
    Enhanced Zoom Desktop, 
    Expo, 
    Fading Windows, 
    Ubuntu Unity Plugin,

general options->desktop size->horizontal virtual size 4 & vertical virtual size 1.

desktop cube->transparent cude->opacity during rotating 50,000

rotate cude->general->zoom 1,000.

desktop cube->appearance-/skydome change the 3 first settings

(I do not have gpu driver installed because I had some issues, all texts was cloudy, couldn't read anything,but same issue happened with driver too.)

*driver installed, had to uncheck fxaa to fix the issue.problem still exist

I ran this test

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

and all was "yes".

my systeam : ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit, 
             AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor × 6,
             gpu nvidia gtx 560, 
             16giga ram